Formula to compare data separated by comma in one cell with another 3 cell's value
I have [female,unspecified] in B2 cell.
In column D, I have male in D1 cell, female in D2 cell and unspecified in D3 cell.
I need formula to calculate missing value in B2 cell compared to the values in cells D1 to D3.
Raw data

Desired output in C2 cell


Seems like your question is not about SQL in any way so I've removed the irrelevant tags.

You can use FILTER + COUNTIF:
=FILTER(D1:D3,0=COUNTIF(SPLIT(B2,",[]"),D1:D3))


Or FILTER + REGEXMATCH:
=FILTER(D1:D3,1-REGEXMATCH(B2,"(?i)\b"&D1:D3&"\b"))


Or FILTER + XMATCH:
=FILTER(D1:D3,ISNA(XMATCH(D1:D3,SPLIT(B2,",[]"))))


